# To which extent can we use the data of healthsite.io - can we use maps etc. too?

Tags: python, postgis, openstreetmap

To which extent we can use the data of healthsite.io?

Healthsites.io is a very interesting project which takes the collaboratively gathered data to a new level The latest project features along with cutting-edge use cases.

To which extent can I use the data of healthsites.io - Can I use the maps too?
can we use the data-extracts and the Maps too!?

are they released under the: Open Data License (ODBL)

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Global_Healthsites_Mapping_Project

https://github.com/healthsites/healthsites/wiki/healthsites.io-license

**guess**: Since the data is released under Open Data License (ODBL), have a look at the TLDR Legal for ODBL. 
**that said**: it seems like  we can use the data since it indeed fits the conditions of the license.

Guess that we can use:

- Data extracts per country are available on Healthsites.io, which can be found by going to the map page and browsing the country list on the left panel. Clicking on the name of any country listed will show a dashboard for that country which includes a link for downloading the associated data as a shapefile.
- Can we use the data-extracts and the Maps too!?

Comment: Legal questions really ought to be directed to the lawyer you pay to render such opinions. Free opinions on the web aren't worth half what they cost.

Comment: I think any question about open data is more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: hi Vince  and hello PolyGeo - many thanks for the hints - convinced - i head over to openData. Many many thanks for all you do here - i really love the gis-page here. Keep up the great work - it rocks

Answer (score 2):

healthsites.io uses OpenStreetMap data and per ODbL, you free to use this data in whatever way so far as you attribute OpenStreetMap Contributors. Find out about OSM copyright [here](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright) if you have any further questions kindly contact project lead.